# Returning a modified docstring from an attribute wrapped method

Tags: python

I have an attribute wrapper class along these lines:

```
import functools

class wrapper(object):

  def __init__(self, function):
    self.function = function
    functools.update_wrapper(self, function)

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do some stuff here first
    return self.function(self.obj, *args, **kwargs)

  def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    self.cls = owner
    self.obj = instance
    return self.__call__
```

And then I can wrap some method Bar.foo:

```
class Bar:
  @wrapper
  def foo(self):
    """ This is the docstring I want to see """
    pass
```

Now, if I create some instance of Bar, and look at Bar.foo, it is obviously a wrapper, and it does not have a docstring. I'd like to somehow patch things so that the original docstring from the wrapped function shows up (even better, I'd like to modify it slightly to include the fact that it is wrapped). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that decorators in form of class do not work in the same way as "usual" decorators (in form of functions). `update_wrapper` updates attributes of decorator instance, but when you apply that decorator to a method of a class, `__doc__` and other attributes actually will be taken from `__call__` method of the decorator's class (because you return `__call__` from `__get__`). Example:

```
import functools

class wrapper1(object):
    """This is the wrapper1 class"""
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        """This is the wrapper1.__init__"""
        self.wrapped = wrapped
        functools.update_wrapper(self, wrapped)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """This is the wrapper1.__call__"""
        print "__call__ of wrapper1.__call__"
        if hasattr(self, 'obj'):
            return self.wrapped(self.obj, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        self.cls = owner
        self.obj = instance
        return self.__call__


def wrapper2(wrapped):
    @functools.wraps(wrapped)
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print "_wrapper of wrapper2 decorator"
        return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapper


@wrapper1
def f1():
    """The f1 function"""
    print "f1 call"


@wrapper2
def f2():
    """The f2 function"""
    print "f2 call"

print "call of f1: '{}'".format(f1.__doc__)
f1()

print "call of f2: '{}'".format(f2.__doc__)
f2()

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, desc):
        self.desc = desc

    @wrapper1
    def m1(self):
        """The A.m1 method"""
        print "A.m1 call: {}".format(self.desc)

    @wrapper2
    def m2(self):
        """The A.m2 method"""
        print "A.m2 call: {}".format(self.desc)

a = A('Hello!')

print "Call of A.m2: {}: {}".format(a.m2.__doc__, A.m2.__doc__)
a.m2()

print "Call of A.m1: {}: {}".format(a.m1.__doc__, A.m1.__doc__)
a.m1()
```

Last two lines print out:

```
Call of A.m1: This is the wrapper1.__call__: This is the wrapper1.__call__
__call__ of wrapper1.__call__
A.m1 call: Hello!
```

If the form of decorators does not really matter, then use decorators as `def wrapper(wrapped):`. It is simpler and clearer.
But if you still want to use class form of decorator for some reasons, then change `__get__` method to return `self`, it will fix undesired behaviour:

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    self.cls = owner
    self.obj = instance
    return self
```

Comment: Thank you! Making the change you suggested gives me the correct docstring. Now, to push my luck, is there any way to get the original parameters to be shown? This is in IPython, and if I enter a method name followed by '(' and wait a second, I get a popup with the doctring and method signature. The method signature is now just showing as (self, *args, **kwargs). I'm guessing IPython might be doing this with introspection and it can't be changed but it would be great if it could.

Answer (score 1):

As Aleksandr pointed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30341746/471899) `__doc__` will be taken from `__call__` method of `wrapper` class

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) states, that `__doc__` is a read-only attribute of user-defined methods, but function's `__doc__` isn't.

So call `functools.update_wrapper` on `self.__call__.__func__` instead of `self` inside `__init__` method.

If you want to modify the original docstring then you may do it with following code

```
self.__call__.__func__.__doc__ = self.__call__.__doc__ + ' added later'
```